# jquery multi dimension forloop json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

Dears

I am struggling to get the below screen working
[Project progress screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Oqn.png)
Below is the json i generated from PHP, MYSQL. I want the project alongside the user images and names when mouseover.  I tried forloop inside foloop and foreach options.

please let me know if there are issues with the json, jquery

```
array = {  "Citi Bank": [
{
  "users": "Steve Mathew",
  "image": "img/user/stevemathew.jpg"
}  ],  "Amex Bank": [
{
  "users": "Jonas",
  "image": "img/user/jonas.png"
},
{
  "users": "Mark",
  "image": "img/user/mark.png"
},
{
  "users": "Steve Mathew",
  "image": "img/user/stevemathew.jpg"
},
{
  "users": "Sue",
  "image": "img/user/sue.png"
}  ],  "HFC": [
{
  "users": "Steve Mathew",
  "image": "img/user/stevemathew.jpg"
}  ],  "RBANK": [
{
  "users": "Jonas",
  "image": "img/user/jonas.png"
},
{
  "users": "Steve Mathew",
  "image": "img/user/stevemathew.jpg"
}  ],  "New Prospect": [
{
  "users": "Steve Mathew",
  "image": "img/user/stevemathew.jpg"
} ]}
```

i have tried the html and jquery as below

```js
function progress(){
 
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
  url: 'project.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result){
 var myJson=JSON.stringify(result);
 
console.log(myJson);

$("#zbt tr").remove();
    var txt = "";
                var len = myJson.length;
                var txt = "<tr><td>"+"<b>Prospect</b>"+"</td><td>"+"<b>Count</b>"+"</td></tr>";
    var txt = "<tr><td>"+"<b>S.No</b>"+"</td><td>"+"<b>Prospect</b>"+"</td><td>"+"<b>Users</b>"+"</td>";
    var i,j,arrayItem;
                if(len > 0){
                    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
       txt += "<tr><td>"+1+"</td><td><a>"+myJson[i]+"</a><br/></td><td>"
       txt += "<ul class='list-inline'><br>";
       for (j = 0; j < arrayItem[i].length; j++) {
       txt += "<li><img src='"+myJson[i][j].image+"' title='"+myJson[i][j].users+"' class='user-image' alt='Avatar' style=width:50% class='img-circle'></li><br>";
       }
       txt += "</ul></td><br>";       
     }
     console.log(txt);
                    }
                    if(txt != ""){
                        $("#zbt").append(txt);
                    } 
                },
error: function(e){ 
console.log(e);
} 
})
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="zbt" border='1' style="width: auto; height: auto; box-shadow: 5px 5px 6px rgba(41, 38, 38, 0.55);  max-width: 400px;">
     <b><tr class='clickable-row' font size="3">
     <td>S.No</td><td>Prospect</td><td>Users</td><td>Progress</td><td>Trend</td>
     </tr>
     </b>
     </table>
```

Any and every inputs would be of great help!!

Best regards

Comment: why are you using `JSON.stringify`? Surely you want to keep this as an array of objects, not convert it back into a string? (Also, that JSON deserialises into an object, not an array.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an *object*, you can't loop over it, like you'd loop over the array.

What you can do is to convert your object to array using `Object.entries`

```
var realArray = Object.entries(array);
```

That will give you array with 2 entries, one for the key and another for the value. You can loop over the array with `for` loop then.

Another solution would be to use `for in` loop over the object itself.

For example:

```
for (var key in array) {
  // key is the name of the entry key
  // use array[key] to access the entries
  console.log(key, array[key]);
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks Sasa. The for(var key in array) works fine. but one question. how do i get the array[key] separated for each value i..e user and image? when i tried alert instead of console, i get undefined error.

Comment: Hey Vidhyalaksmi, each of your objects contains a single-entry array, so to access the `users` or `image`, you need to use the index. For example `for (var key in array) console.log(array[key][0]["users"], array[key][0]["image"]);`

Comment: while the first record works fine, its failing in the second record. i tried each and foreach loop but its still failing. `for (var key in result) {
 console.log([key][0]); /*<-- for prospect*/
  console.log(result[key][0]["users"], result[key][0]["image"]);
console.log(result[1][key]);  <- failing here
  console.log(result[key][1]["users"], result[key][1]["image"]);
}`  withe the error **main:863 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Addis Credit' of undefined
    at Object.success (main:863)**

Comment: OK. Managed to solve this with the below '  
$.each(result, function (key, data) {
 alert(key)    
   $.each(data, function (index, data) {
 alert(data.users);
 alert(data.image);
    })
})
 '